# SPO filter webpart with folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, filter, folder, classic-experience

Our customer has a document library with a big folder structure in SharePoint Online (classic).

We need to display that library as a web part filtered by a specific metadata in another page. That's easy of course, but the web part should display all the folder structure, and then inside the folders, only the filtered documents.

I've edited the web part view, but if I tick Show items inside folders, the web part is empty. If I tick Show all items without folders, I can see the filtered documents, but not the folder structure.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Document Library A - Document Set Welcome page
Webpart (Document Library B view filtered by document set A ID)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new view and set the filter，**Content Type is equal to Folder Or specific metadata equals value**:

[image]

Then change the view in the document library web part to display that library filtered by a specific metadata and also display all the folder structure.

Comment: Thanks but the specific metadata is dynamic. The webpart displayed in a document set welcome page and need to be filtered by the docset id.